# Go back to parent activity if child activity crashes

Tags: android, android-intent, exception, android-activity, android-webview

In my app there are two activities. Activity 1 is a webview (== main activity). Activity 2 is a native pdf reader (child activity). If certain links are clicked, activity 1 opens activity 2 via intent. The intent does not use any specific flags. If the user finished reading the pdf he closes activity 2. Another intent is triggered and the user gets to the point he started (Activity 1). So far no problem!

Unfortunately, the pdf reader is still buggy and crashes sometimes.
In those cases i want the same behavior as mentioned above: the user should get to the point he started (Activity 1). 
In Activity 2 i integrated a  class implementing the UncaughtExceptionHandler-interface to catch any uncatched exception and handle it in the uncaughtException-method. But the best result i accomplished there was the recreation of activity 1.

Is my goal unreachable? Or with other words, if a child activity crashes, the best what you can get is the recreation of the parent activity (== main activity)?

**EDIT:**

With Alexander's answer i found a solution:

AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name="de.fcms.webapp.CoreActivity"
        android:label="@string/label_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="de.fcms.framework.module.PdfActivity"
        android:label="@string/setting_activity_name"
        android:parentActivityName="de.fcms.webapp.CoreActivity" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PdfActivity"
        android:process="de.fcms.framework.PdfActivity">
    </activity>
```

PdfActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

            PdfActivity.this.getBackToMainActivity();
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        }
    });

    //let's force a crash
    throw new OutOfMemoryError();
}

private void getBackToMainActivity () {

    getLogger().debug("getBackToMainACtivity");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CoreActivity.class);
    setResult(2001, intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: when activity2 is completed then if you click back button, you can move to previous activity ??my question can you tell me why activity2 is crashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to run Activity2 in a separate process. Just add `android:process` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
     <activity
         android:name=".Activity2"
         android:process="com.example.myapp.activity2"/>
```

Note that process name is required to have at least one '.' and it is what you'll see in the `adb shell top`. I.e. it should be unique. So I would recommend to use you application id + activity name.

Alternative you can make the process private to your app (and that's what you probably want most of the time). To do so, you prepend process name with colon (`:`). In this case, you don't have to worry about global name uniqueness and can use shorter one:

```
         android:process=":activity2"
```

Read more [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html).

Comment: Thx, your advice helped me out. I reached my goal now.